# How to find the current consumed by an STM32 Nucleo-144 board

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, current-measurement, nucleo

I'm trying to find the current consumed by ST Nucleo board for one of my applications to understand how it can be minimized on requirements.

Comment: We don't know what's your application. We don't know if you plan to plug in a 100 LEDs or so to the board. So this cannot be answered.

Answer (score 1):

It depends which MCU it has and what features you use.

You can't find it, you need to measure it based on what features you need and when features that you don't need are disabled. Even if features are disabled, the fact that the components are still present on board will still cause some current consumption.

Comment: Yes, agreed. Still how can one find the current consumption irrespective of what all peripherals enabled or disabled.

Comment: What prevents you from measuring what the consumption is to find how much it is? They surely won't list how much will the different hardware parts consume separately. Like regulator quiescent current, or ST-link prorammer whether it is used or not.

Comment: I'm not interested to find individual current consumed by each peripheral. Want to find the overall consumption

Comment: You will only find it by measuring it. And I did not mean internal peripherals but components on Nucleo board. There are a lot of other things other than the MCU on the Nucleo boards that consume current. Besides you never said which MCU this is. There are many different MCU models you can have on a Nucleo-144 board. There is a big differece if you run an F2 at 32 kHz or H7 at 480 MHz.

Answer (score 1):

Read the STM32 Nucleo-144 User Manual, particularly the description of JP5.

> Jumper JP5, labeled IDD, is used to measure the STM32 microcontroller
> consumption by removing the jumper and by connecting an ammeter:
>
> - JP5 ON: STM32 is powered (default)
> - JP5 OFF: an ammeter must be connected to measure the STM32 current. If there is no ammeter, the STM32 is not powered
>
> To get a correct current consumption, the Ethernet PHY should
> be set in power-down mode or SB13 should be removed. Refer to Section
> 6.11: Ethernet for details.